# comparison of Time with nil failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I get the error comparison of Time with nil failed. I see that both the time values getting printed perfectly, but still the `distance_of_time_in_words` throws the error.

```
<%= comment.created_at %> //2014-05-29 07:47:18 UTC
<%= comment.article.created_at %> //2014-05-29 07:44:22 UTC 
<p>Posted <%= distance_of_time_in_words(comment.article.created_at,
                                      comment.created_at) %> later </p>
```

Comment: Please show us the `distance_of_time_in_words` method.

Comment: @Tamer, it's a Rails built-in. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html

Comment: Troubleshoot with intermediate variables, perhaps they don't contain what you think. Also check for typos.

Comment: My guess is it's an issue with the first argument as the second defaults to `0`. Is this exactly how the file looks in your app?

Comment: Just to be certain that those values you've put in comments are correct, can you log them out and check?